# How many usb devices connected to Android Raspbery Pi 3?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, usb, device, enumeration

I'm using Android Raspberry Pi 3 and I want to know how many USB devices connected to it.
I know how do do it for camera devices:

`Log.d(TAG, "how many camera device? -->" + Camera.getNumberOfCameras());`

but I don't know how determine many other USB devices connected to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in [Andoid USB Host guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html#working-d), you can enumerate USB host devices with :

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
Log.v(TAG, "There are : " + deviceList.size() + " USB devices connected");
```

You can iterate them with :

```
Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
    UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();

}
```